# How to store values from a normal array to a 2D array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I want to store the Values to the CustomValues array. How can I do this?
Any code and explanation would be great.

```
int main() {
    int CustomValues[4][3];

    int Values[3] = {234, 98, 0};
    int Values1[3] = {21, 34, 5};
    int Values2[3] = { 12, 6, 765 };
    int Values3[3] = { 54, 67, 76 };
}
```

The CustomValues array should look like:

```
{{234, 98, 0}, { 21, 34, 5 }, { 12, 6, 765 }, { 54, 67, 76 }}
```

Comment: How about this: [https://ideone.com/26oyXf](https://ideone.com/26oyXf) `int CustomValues[4][3]{{234, 98, 0}, { 21, 34, 5 }, { 12, 6, 765 }, { 54, 67, 76 }};`

Comment: I can't do this because I'm making something that gets user input and stores it in a array and if the user wants to saves it, it saves it into a 2d array. And I don't know how to store, edit, delete 2d arrays.

Comment: yes there will always be 3 values and the amount of times the person can save it is 4

Comment: cant you use try block to store, if there is an array is probably because the array size is not big enough so you could just then send a message. Sorry I'm to C++.

Comment: But that's not the problem, I just need to know how to store values from the 1D array to the 2D array.

Comment: I just need to know how to store and then I could do the rest myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different ways you can do this. Since we already know your constraints, I've taken liberties to not do this dynamically.

The first is `memcpy`, which is in the `<cstring>` header:

```
memcpy(CustomValues[0], Values, sizeof(Values));
memcpy(CustomValues[1], Values1, sizeof(Values1));
memcpy(CustomValues[2], Values2, sizeof(Values2));
memcpy(CustomValues[3], Values3, sizeof(Values3));
```

Another is to loop through the array and store the values individually:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(CustomValues)/sizeof(CustomValues[0]); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(CustomValues[0])/sizeof(CustomValues[0][0]); j++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            CustomValues[i][j] = Values[j];
        }
        else if (i == 1) {
            CustomValues[i][j] = Values1[j];
        }
        else if (i == 2) {
            CustomValues[i][j] = Values2[j];
        }
        else if (i == 3) {
            CustomValues[i][j] = Values3[j];
        }
    }
}
```

There is probably a better way to handle the logic for selecting which `Values` array you want, but that was just a quick solution to demonstrate.

**EDIT: Example of 2D Vector usage**

This example doesn't contain the logic for actually controlling the number of elements in a vector, but you can simply do that by following the `for` loop logic. Basically, you just need something to check the size of your vector with `size()`, and then move to a different one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> CustomValues; //2D vector

    //1D vectors
    vector<int> Values;
    vector<int> Values1;

    Values.push_back(234); //to insert a value individually
    Values.insert(Values.end(), {98, 0}); //to append multiple values

    Values1.insert(Values1.end(), {21, 34, 5});

    //inserting the 1D arrays to the 2D arrays
    CustomValues.push_back(Values);
    CustomValues.push_back(Values1);

    //example of getting # of elements
    int countOfInnerVectors = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < CustomValues.size(); i++)
        countOfInnerVectors++;

    cout << "The number of 1D vectors in CustomValues is: " << countOfInnerVectors;
}
```

An example of checking for the correct amount of vectors would be:

```
//check if we have less than 10 inner vectors
int maxCustomValuesSize = 10;
if (CustomValues2.size() < maxCustomValuesSize)
```

In this example, you would have something like `int index = 0`, and when that `if` is no longer satisfied, you could do `index++` or some other logic to start inserts at your new index, like `CustomValues2[index].push_back(Values);`.

You can follow the same logic for the inner vectors as well, you would just be changing to a new 1D array instead of changing to a new "row" like the outer vector does.

Comment: Say if I have more values, do I just add more of 'memcpy(CustomValues[3], Values3, sizeof(Values3));' and add more if statesments?

Comment: yeah, more arrays. do i just add more 'memcpy(CustomValues[3], Values3, sizeof(Values3));' and change some of the numbers. or add more if statesments for the second method

Comment: But how would I use it if I make it so the size of the 2D array is 10, then you have one 1D array. The 1D array's value change depending of what the user inputed. For example if the user inputed 10 10 10 , then the value of the 1D array is {10, 10, 10}. And if the user types saves then the array is saved to the 2D array and they can only save 10 different values for the 1D array, 10 times.

Comment: Because right now having multiple 1D arrays is kinda inefficient. And I'm making this to be put inside a Ardiuno Uno for a circuit I'm making.

Comment: I want to limit down their saves so it is easy to use the circuit and doesn't crash. If it is to complicated to make t sure there can only be 10, then its fine, I just need something that saves and deletes stuff in a 2d array .And I have no idea what a vector is all I know is in math they are a line with a direction and in coding they are usually used in 3D games. And what do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: oh ok, so how do I use it. Sounds easy.

Comment: Alright, I'll be waiting.

Comment: how do you print out a vector? It spits out an error `C++ no operator matches these operands            operand types are: std::ostream << std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>>`